# 'using namespace {some namespace nested inside of another}`

Tags: c++, namespaces

Is it possible to access the type `Foo` under the namespace `first` by using a using declaration (or something similar) in the caller code?

```
namespace first {
    namespace second {
        struct Foo { int i; }; 
    } 
} 

int main() {
    using namespace first::second; 
    first::Foo foo { 123 }; 
    return 0; 
}
```

I get these error messages:

````
error: 'Foo' is not a member of 'first'
  first::Foo foo{ 123 };```
````

Comment: What is _"something like this"_?

Comment: Have you tried yourself before asking? Having any issues with your code? By the way, why you declare as first::Foo while the struct Foo is inside second?

Comment: @ThomasSablik access the type `Foo` under namespace `first`.

Comment: @armagedescu yes I have tried, and that was part of the question. Sorry I didn't make it clear enough.

Comment: Then you should edit the question with the compiler error messages that you got.

Comment: If you tried, what are the exact problems you are experiencing?

Comment: I made edits to question providing the error messages and making my question more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several options:

1. ```
   using namespace first::second; 
   Foo foo{123};
   ```
2. ```
   namespace ns = first::second; 
   ns::Foo foo{123};
   ```
3. I guess you could also do `namespace first = first::second;`. Then `first::Foo foo{123};` would work, but to access the contents of the actual `namespace first` (other than those in `namespace second`) you'll have to use `::first`.

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces can be expanded and you can create an alias to a token in a different namespace:

```
namespace first {
    namespace second {
        struct Foo { int i; }; 
    } 
}

namespace first {
    using second::Foo;
}

int main() {
    first::Foo foo { 123 }; 
    return 0; 
}
```